# Analog controller not working?

Tags: java, android, andengine

```
final int x1=0;
final int y1= CAMERA_HEIGHT-(int)this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion.getHeight();
final AnalogOnScreenControl velocityOnScreenController = new AnalogOnScreenControl(x1, y1, this.mCamera,this.mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion, 
            this.mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion,0.1f,this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager(), new IAnalogOnScreenControlListener(){

                @Override
                public void onControlChange(
                        BaseOnScreenControl pBaseOnScreenControl,
                        float pValueX, float pValueY) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    spaceshipPhysicsHandler.setVelocity(pValueX * 50,pValueY * 50);

                }

                @Override
                public void onControlClick(
                        AnalogOnScreenControl pAnalogOnScreenControl) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // do nothing on click

                }
        });
     this.mScene.setChildScene(velocityOnScreenController);
```

All the controller base and knob are all set. It appear on the screen perfectly but the problem is it does nothing. Its knob doesn't move and the onControllerChange() method is never called. What wrong i am doing here? Do i need to keep it in some kind of update method()? It just like a picture of controller doing nth.

Comment: i got this. Just i didn't made a callback on onPopulateScene() method

Comment: Is it solved? Please could you post that as your answer, then choose it and close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    velocityOnScreenController.getControlBase().setBlendFunction(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA,  GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    velocityOnScreenController.getControlBase().setAlpha(0.5f);
    velocityOnScreenController.setOnControlClickEnabled(true);

  this.mScene.setChildScene(velocityOnScreenController);
  OnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
```

// here you need to make the callback i don't know how this solved the problem but
 it solved the above problem...